# Clientwidth and offsetWidth return different value compared to browser ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

i have a strange behaviour with my javascript code. I want to get the width of a `<div>` container via javascript code but it doesnt return me the same size like the ui of chrome/ firefox sais.
I tried to get the width of a specific div container in three different ways:
1. Width .offsetWidth
2. Width the getBoundingClientRect() function
3. With jquery and width()

All three give me kind of the same back but the browser show me a different width. I get the browser width via right click -> inspect element -> hover over the specific element and it will show you the px width.

For example is the browser div width 971px and the javascript width returns me 761px. What am doing wrong here?

I have the actual code down below (but dont really know on how to use it correctly :( ).

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container');


let offsetWidth = container.offsetWidth;
let boundingWidth = container.getBoundingClientRect().width
let jqueryWidth = $('#container').width();
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.rows {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto hidden;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.rows}> {/* Here is some code */}</div>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me and if you need any further information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The JS methods (I tested using `.clientWidth` and `.clientHeight` but others should be similar) include padding and margin values.

say for example we have a div width of 638px in chrome, width horizontal padding 8px, running `clientWidth` will result 654. (638 base + 8 padding-left + 8 padding-left). 
Then, let's add `margin-left:10px` we now **loose** 10px from our value to now get 644. (638 base + 8 padding-left + 8 padding-right - 10 margin-left)

Does this help?

EDIT: You can test this for yourself in Chrome inspector as I did. Use the Chrome console to run local JS easily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the problem is that i dont use margin/ padding and that i dont loose like 10px. I loose like 200 pixels. So Firefox/ Chrome sais that the div should be 858px width and the js functions say 648px. This confuses me so much